How to prevent views from destroying in my custom tab bar in SwiftUI?
I have my own TabBar because native SwiftUI's TabBar has many restrictions. Here is a code:
enum Tab: CaseIterable {
    case myWords
    case addWord
    case training
    case settings
}

@Themed struct TabBarView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .myWords
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                switch selectedTab {
                case .myWords: makeNavigationView(for: .myWords) { MyWordsView() }
                case .addWord: makeNavigationView(for: .addWord) { AddWordView() }
                case .training: makeNavigationView(for: .training) { QuickTrainingView() }
                case .settings: makeNavigationView(for: .settings) { SettingsView() }
                }
                
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    TabButton(text: "My words", image: "Tabs/Words", selected: makeBinding(for: .myWords))
                    TabButton(text: "Add word", image: "Tabs/Add", selected: makeBinding(for: .addWord))
                    TabButton(text: "Training", image: "Tabs/Play", selected: makeBinding(for: .training))
                    TabButton(text: "Settings", image: "Tabs/Settings", selected: makeBinding(for: .settings))
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
        }
    }
    
    private func makeNavigationView(for tab: Tab, content: () -> some View) -> some View {
        NavigationView {
            content()
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .navigationTitle(String(localeKey: tab.title))
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .accentColor(theme.color(.lightBlue))
    }
    
    private func makeBinding(for tab: Tab) -> Binding <Bool> {
        Binding <Bool>(get: { selectedTab == tab },
                       set: { if $0 == true { selectedTab = tab } })
    }
}

The problem is when I switch to another view (change selectedTab to another value), the previous view's state is lost. So when I go back my tab view is recreated and lost its state. Especially it's annoying when I navigate in NavigationView inside of my tab. So I cannot understand how to "cache" my tab views, I mean save their state or prevent to recreating these views. Maybe I just should to hide views, but I don't understand how to do it

You would indeed need to render all of the different tab views at all times and somehow hide the ones that aren't selected. Either that or  avoid ’@State` in the tab views and persist their state in an observable that you keep around

"somehow hide the ones that aren't selected" - how? I cannot find any adequate solution for hiding views without recreating them

I wrote a custom tab view here. The question itself is about transitions, but you can ignore all the stuff related to custom transitions. At the very end I demonstrated how to preserve view state using opacity. Just use that code.

@Sweeper yes, it works with opacity modifier. But what about performance? Is that works fine?

@chudin26 are you saying that the other views will stay in memory even when they are not displayed, and that this would cause performance issues? Well, the built-in TabView keeps the other undisplayed tabs in memory too. There is no magic. If you want to keep all the state, it gotta be in memory. If you only care about navigation state and not others (e.g. scroll position), there are potentially other ways things can do.
